# are the regular topology on $\mathbb R$ and the product topology on $\omega^\omega$ equivalent?

Tags: general-topology, descriptive-set-theory, the-baire-space

are the regular topology on $\mathbb R$ and the product topology on $\omega^\omega$ equivalent?

By the product topology on $\omega^\omega$ I mean the topology in which an open basis set is a set of all sequence which has the same finite prefix.

If the answer is no, then, is one of them finer then the other?

Thank you!

Comment: In what sense you want to compare $\omega^\omega$ with $\mathbb R$. If you are looking at the embedding $\omega^\omega \cong \mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q \subseteq \mathbb R$ via continued fractions, then the answer is: Yes, $\omega^\omega$ is homeomorphic with the irrationals.

Comment: Why would one of them refine the other?

Answer (score 3):

Note that the topology on $\Bbb R$ is connected and locally compact, whereas the topology on $\omega^\omega$ is totally disconnected and every compact set has an empty interior. So the two of them are very different from one another.

For what it's worth, though, $\Bbb R$ can be obtained as a continuous image of $\omega^\omega$.